# pandas: efficiently apply function that uses as input the whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, feature-extraction

I have a pandas dataframe that models product purchases according to dates. I want to add features of how many purchases happened yesterday, last week etc. Is there an elegant and efficient way to do that? Now I am doing a loop, which takes a lot of time..

Given the data:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
dico = {"dates":["2017-11-20"]*3+["2017-11-21"]*3+ ["2017-11-22"]*3, "product":["A", "B", "C"]*3, "sales": np.arange(1,10)}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dico)
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)
```

to obtain the sales of the previous days and sum of sales of previous two days I loop:

```
one_day = pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')
two_days = pd.to_timedelta(2, unit='d')

yesterday_sales, last_two_days_sales = [], []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    yesterday_performance = df.loc[(df["product"] == row["product"]) & (df.dates == (row["dates"]-one_day)) ]
    if yesterday_performance.shape[0] == 1:
        yesterday_sales.append(yesterday_performance.sales.values[0])
    else:
        yesterday_sales.append(-1)

    two_days_sales = df.loc[(df["product"] == row["product"]) & (df["dates"] >= (row["dates"]-two_days)) & (df["dates"] < (row["dates"]))]
    if two_days_sales.shape[0] >= 1:
        last_two_days_sales.append(two_days_sales.sales.sum())
    else:
        last_two_days_sales.append(-1)

df["yesterday_sales"] = yesterday_sales
df["last_two_days_sales"] = last_two_days_sales
```

Everything in the loop is time consuming, but I can not think of a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code a little. It's still not vectorised, but if performance is not an issue it should be easier to maintain:

```
def one_day(row):
    yday_perf = df.loc[(df['product'] == row['product']) & (df['dates'] == (row['dates'] + pd.Timedelta(days=-1))), 'sales']    
    return yday_perf.values[0] if not yday_perf.empty else -1

def two_day(row):
    twoday_perf = df.loc[(df['product'] == row['product']) & (df['dates'] >= (row['dates'] + pd.Timedelta(days=-2))) & (df['dates'] < row['dates']), 'sales']
    return twoday_perf.sum() if len(twoday_perf) >=1 else -1

df['yesterday_sales'] = df.apply(one_day, axis=1)
df['last_two_days_sales'] = df.apply(two_day, axis=1)

#        dates product  sales  yesterday_sales  last_two_days_sales
# 0 2017-11-20       A      1               -1                   -1
# 1 2017-11-20       B      2               -1                   -1
# 2 2017-11-20       C      3               -1                   -1
# 3 2017-11-21       A      4                1                    1
# 4 2017-11-21       B      5                2                    2
# 5 2017-11-21       C      6                3                    3
# 6 2017-11-22       A      7                4                    5
# 7 2017-11-22       B      8                5                    7
# 8 2017-11-22       C      9                6                    9
```

Comment: It helps. Do you have any idea for making it faster also?

Comment: you could try and combine the 2 `apply` calls into 1 and assign it to 2 series simultaneously. your function would have to return a `tuple`.